# How to fix No setter/field for id found on class com.example.chatappfirebase.Model.User?

Tags: java, android, firebase

trying to pull out all the users from my Firebase database then display it on my app, I've got an error saying

```
No setter/field for id found on class com.example.chatappfirebase.Model.User
```

but my User class getters and setters are generated from android studio

my User Class Code :

```
package com.example.chatappfirebase.Model;


public class User {

    private String userId;
    private String username;
    private String ImageURL;

    public User(String userId, String username, String imageURL) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        ImageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return ImageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        ImageURL = imageURL;
    }
}
```

when I try to pull out the users list from the database

```
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            users.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    assert firebaseUser != null;
                    if (!user.getUserId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        users.add(user);
                    }

            }

            userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), users);


   recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }
```

[image]

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.chatappfirebase.Fragments.UsersFragment$1.onDataChange(UsersFragment.java:65)
```

which is this line of code :

```
if (!user.getUserId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {}
```

Comment: User user  = new User();

user.snapshot.getValue(User.class); 

Make this changes and check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55940666/10182897) for explanation.

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String imageURL;

    public User(String id, String username, String imageURL) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setUserId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        imageURL = imageURL;
    }
}
```